# Azure Template Spec Deploy shows error as "You will need to Agree to the terms of service below to create this resource successfully"

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-virtual-machine, azure-rm-template, azure-resource-group

The Vnet, Subnet, NSG, Virtual Machine, etc. are created in a Resource group on one Subscription and downloaded template via Export template option in Resource Group.

This template is imported to another subcription and stored as Template Spec and updated new subcription id instead old subscription.

if I deploy this template, I am getting the following error in the Review + create tab.
"You will need to Agree to the terms of service below to create this resource successfully."

Please find the screenshot.
[image]

There is no checkbox and not sure if I have to update the template to avoid this issue.
Please advise.

Please find the template in [github](https://github.com/Rajanusa/Azure-TemplateSpec.git)

I am not able to export the template and use that either in the same subscription or other subscription. Since I am practicing Azure every time I have to start from begining.
I want to save the resource as a template, delete it and use it again when I practice next time. Please advise for this use case.

How
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**We have tried the same to create Virtual machines ,vnet, NSG, Nic etc. from our end after exporting the template and it works fine** .

**NOTE 1:-** ***When we are exporting the template for Vms there is zone in it. Make sure that you have removed when you are trying to deploy from your environment tools.***

*Template that we used, You can also try the same sample script in your environment with providing your requirements name and details many times for hands-on:-*

`example.json`:-

```
{
"$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
"contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
"parameters": {
"location": {
"type": "string"
},
"networkInterfaceName1": {
"type": "string"
},
"enableAcceleratedNetworking": {
"type": "bool"
},
"networkSecurityGroupName": {
"type": "string"
},
"networkSecurityGroupRules": {
"type": "array"
},
"subnetName": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualNetworkName": {
"type": "string"
},
"addressPrefixes": {
"type": "array"
},
"subnets": {
"type": "array"
},
"publicIpAddressName1": {
"type": "string"
},
"publicIpAddressType": {
"type": "string"
},
"publicIpAddressSku": {
"type": "string"
},
"pipDeleteOption": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineName": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineName1": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineComputerName1": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineRG": {
"type": "string"
},
"osDiskType": {
"type": "string"
},
"osDiskDeleteOption": {
"type": "string"
},
"virtualMachineSize": {
"type": "string"
},
"nicDeleteOption": {
"type": "string"
},
"adminUsername": {
"type": "string"
},
"adminPassword": {
"type": "secureString"
},
"patchMode": {
"type": "string"
},
"enableHotpatching": {
"type": "bool"
}

},
"variables": {
"nsgId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
"vnetName": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
"vnetId": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name,'Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
"subnetRef": "[concat(variables('vnetId'), '/subnets/', parameters('subnetName'))]"
},
"resources": [
{
"name": "[parameters('networkInterfaceName1')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces",
"apiVersion": "2021-03-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"dependsOn": [
"[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups/', parameters('networkSecurityGroupName'))]",
"[concat('Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/', parameters('virtualNetworkName'))]",
"[concat('Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses/', parameters('publicIpAddressName1'))]"
],
"properties": {
"ipConfigurations": [
{
"name": "ipconfig1",
"properties": {
"subnet": {
"id": "[variables('subnetRef')]"
},
"privateIPAllocationMethod": "Dynamic",
"publicIpAddress": {
"id": "[resourceId(resourceGroup().name, 'Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses', parameters('publicIpAddressName1'))]",
"properties": {
                              "deleteOption": "[parameters('pipDeleteOption')]"
}
}
}
}
],
"enableAcceleratedNetworking": "[parameters('enableAcceleratedNetworking')]",
"networkSecurityGroup": {
"id": "[variables('nsgId')]"
}
}
},
{
"name": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupName')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups",
"apiVersion": "2019-02-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"properties": {
"securityRules": "[parameters('networkSecurityGroupRules')]"
}
},
{
"name": "[parameters('virtualNetworkName')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks",
"apiVersion": "2020-11-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"properties": {
"addressSpace": {
"addressPrefixes": "[parameters('addressPrefixes')]"
},
"subnets": "[parameters('subnets')]"
}
},
{
"name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressName1')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Network/publicIpAddresses",
"apiVersion": "2020-08-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"properties": {
"publicIpAllocationMethod": "[parameters('publicIpAddressType')]"
},
"sku": {
"name": "[parameters('publicIpAddressSku')]"
},
"zones": [
"1"
]
},
{
"name": "[parameters('virtualMachineName1')]",
"type": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines",
"apiVersion": "2021-07-01",
"location": "[parameters('location')]",
"dependsOn": [
"[concat('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/', parameters('networkInterfaceName1'))]"
],
"properties": {
"hardwareProfile": {
"vmSize": "[parameters('virtualMachineSize')]"
},
"storageProfile": {
"osDisk": {
"createOption": "fromImage",
"managedDisk": {
"storageAccountType": "[parameters('osDiskType')]"
},
"deleteOption": "[parameters('osDiskDeleteOption')]"
},
"imageReference": {
"publisher": "MicrosoftWindowsServer",
"offer": "WindowsServer",
"sku": "2019-datacenter-gensecond",
"version": "latest"
}
},
"networkProfile": {
"networkInterfaces": [
{
"id": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces', parameters('networkInterfaceName1'))]",
"properties": {
"deleteOption": "[parameters('nicDeleteOption')]"
}
}
]
},
"osProfile": {
"computerName": "[parameters('virtualMachineComputerName1')]",
"adminUsername": "[parameters('adminUsername')]",
"adminPassword": "[parameters('adminPassword')]",
"windowsConfiguration": {
"enableAutomaticUpdates": true,
"provisionVmAgent": true,
"patchSettings": {
"enableHotpatching": "[parameters('enableHotpatching')]",
"patchMode": "[parameters('patchMode')]"
}
}
},
"diagnosticsProfile": {
"bootDiagnostics": {
"enabled": true
}
}
}

}
],
"outputs": {
"adminUsername": {
"type": "string",
"value": "[parameters('adminUsername')]"
}
}
}
```

`deploy.parameter.json`:-

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "location": {
            "value": "westus2"
        },
        "networkInterfaceName1": {
            "value": "ajt_z1"
        },
        "enableAcceleratedNetworking": {
            "value": true
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupName": {
            "value": "ajxxx-nsg"
        },
        "networkSecurityGroupRules": {
            "value": []
        },
        "subnetName": {
            "value": "default"
        },
        "virtualNetworkName": {
            "value": "ajxxxx"
        },
        "addressPrefixes": {
            "value": [
                "10.0.0.0/16"
            ]
        },
        "subnets": {
            "value": [
                {
                    "name": "default",
                    "properties": {
                        "addressPrefix": "10.0.0.0/24"
                    }
                }
            ]
        },
        "publicIpAddressName1": {
            "value": "ajx-ip"
        },
        "publicIpAddressType": {
            "value": "Static"
        },
        "publicIpAddressSku": {
            "value": "Standard"
        },
        "pipDeleteOption": {
            "value": "Detach"
        },
        "virtualMachineName": {
            "value": "ajxxxxxx"
        },
        "virtualMachineName1": {
            "value": "ajxxxxxx"
        },
        "virtualMachineComputerName1": {
            "value": "ajxxxxxx"
        },
        "virtualMachineRG": {
            "value": "ajxxxxxx"
        },
        "osDiskType": {
            "value": "Premium_LRS"
        },
        "osDiskDeleteOption": {
            "value": "Delete"
        },
        "virtualMachineSize": {
            "value": "Standard_D2s_v3"
        },
        "nicDeleteOption": {
            "value": "Detach"
        },
        "adminUsername": {
            "value": "xxxistrator1"
        },
        "adminPassword": {
            "value": "xxxxrator@1"
        },
        "patchMode": {
            "value": "AutomaticByOS"
        },
        "enableHotpatching": {
            "value": false
        }
       
    }
}
```

***OUTPUT DETAILS:-***

[image]
[image]

[image]

***NOTE:-2*** ***So if the resource is being created and you are again try to create the same resource with the same name ,It will through error which is genuine.make sure that we are changing the resource name accordingly***

***For more information please refer the below links:-***

-**MICROSOFT DOCUMENTATION:-** [***Create and deploy Virtual machine and its resources using ARM***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/quick-create-template)

Comment: I am using portal to export as well as import. Please advise what should I do when Export the template from Resource group. I facing the problem when I deploy the template. I am using shared resource, everyday it will be cleaned. so I export the template and import t in template spec. it is importing without issue and when I deploy that it gives the problem. I am not using console. Please advise how can I do using portal for my scenario. When I import it only take template not param json. would that be a problem.

Comment: {   "error": {"code": "LinkedAuthorizationFailed",
    "message": "The client '11012022-AS2@xy.onmicrosoft.com' with object id 'bb' has permission to perform action 'Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/write' on scope '/subscriptions/yxa/resourcegroups/Demo-Network-EastUs-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/Demo-WebVM1'; however, it does not have permission to perform action 'write' on the linked scope(s) '/subscriptions/ xxyy/resourceGroups/Demo-Network-EastUS-RG/providers/Microsoft.Compute/disks/Demo-WebVM1_disk1_098' or the linked scope(s) are invalid."
    }
}

Comment: I am getting above error when I deploy